# What is the installation size of a clean build of 4.2?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, storage

This is a pretty simple question, but one that I have not been able to find the answer to.  How much disk/storage space does an installation of Jelly Bean (bonus points for other versions) take up?  I am not looking for a super-accurate answer, as installation size varies from device to device, but more of a ballpark answer in the gigabyte/gibibyte range, such as 1.7 GB.  Or does Android's size vary drastically from device to device?

Comment: I'm curious about this, too.  My phone is advertised with "4 GB of internal storage" but the Settings > Storage screen shows a total of 1.27 GB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, to put this another way:

For Gingerbread, storage space weighs around 95Mb, give or take, including Google Apps, source code 6.5GB, compilation taking up approx 14GB space.

Android's storage space for ICS, weighs around 160Mb, give or take, including Google Apps, source code 9.5GB, compilation - takes up approx 20GB space.

As to JB, have not yet built it, but source code is 12.5GB, compilation takes up around 25GB space, various official JB images hovers around 200Mb mark.

The above ball-park figures above, reflects from GB, ICS and JB. As for the future versions of Android, only time will tell how much more space will be taken up, it will increase, no doubt!

As for the final image build output, this would be dependent on handset, as ROM developers/manufacturers love to add their own bits, hence the inclusion of the "*give or take*" in the above sentences, not to mention carrier bloat-ware so the mileage will vary.

Comment: I don't quite understand two statements: "compilation takes up around _x_ GB" and "including Google Apps".  I can understand that the source code would be bound to be one or two orders of magnitude greater than the compiled binaries, but what do you mean by "compilation takes up around _x_ GB"?  Do you mean that the total space required to compile Android takes up _x_ gigabytes on the host environment?  And by "storage space weighs around 95Mb, give or take, including Google Apps, source code 6.5GB" do you mean **Google Apps + Gingerbread = ~95MB**, or **Google Apps + source = ~6.5GB**?

Comment: What I meant was the compiling of the source code takes up that storage space, albeit it is temporary and can always be wiped. The other is, Google Apps is proprietary and meant inclusion of that on top of the built android version such as Gingerbread is around 95MB. There is no source to Google Apps FYI :)